# JavaFX RadioButtons don‘t work(can‘t select)

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a project that convert different bases but my Radiobuttons are not working. I'm making three different VBoxes to add the Buttons but only the third column is working. I'm quite new into JavaFX so I would appreciate if anyone could help me. thanks! Here's my Code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main extends Application {

private ToggleGroup group;
private TextField txtfield;
private TextField output;
private int base = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    StackPane title = new StackPane();
    Text t = new Text("Gib die Basis und die Zahl ein!");
    t.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    title.getChildren().add(t);
    FlowPane center = new FlowPane();
    center.setPrefSize(400, 300);
    HBox input = new HBox();
    VBox base1 = new VBox();
    VBox base2 = new VBox();
    VBox base3 = new VBox();
    input.setPrefSize(400, 100);
    base1.setPrefSize(50, 150);
    base2.setPrefSize(50, 150);
    base3.setPrefSize(50, 150);
    group = new ToggleGroup();
    for (int i = 2; i < 35; i++) {
        RadioButton b = new RadioButton(String.valueOf(i));
        if (i == 10) {
            b.setSelected(true);
        }
        b.setToggleGroup(group);
        b.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            base = Integer.valueOf(b.getText());
            update();
        });

        if (i % 3 == 2) {
            base1.getChildren().add(b);
            b.setTranslateX(110);
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            base2.getChildren().add(b);
            b.setTranslateX(120);
        } else {
            base3.getChildren().add(b);
            b.setTranslateX(130);
        }
    }
    output = new TextField();
    txtfield = new TextField();
    txtfield.setTranslateY(50);
    txtfield.setTranslateX(100);
    txtfield.setOnKeyTyped(keyEvent -> {
        update();
    });
    input.getChildren().add(txtfield);
    center.getChildren().add(input);
    center.getChildren().add(base1);
    center.getChildren().add(base2);
    center.getChildren().add(base3);
    root.setCenter(center);
    root.setTop(title);
    root.setBottom(output);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void update() {

    try {
        output.setText(String.valueOf(new BigInteger(txtfield.getText(), base)));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        output.setText("Nan");
    }
}
}
```

Here‘s how the program should (and does) look like [image: Appliaction]

Comment: The code you posted is missing quite a lot (what you posted does not compile). Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: **Side Note:** You should do some more studying on JavaFX layouts. There is no reason to manually place your nodes here...

Comment: @Zephyr sorry. Hope the code is now easier to understand.

Comment: I think you mean only the third **column** is working. I suspect the issue is with using a `Stackpane`, which may be blocking mouse events when trying to click on the other two columns. But honestly, the whole layout is kind of a mess and should be reconsidered.

Comment: @Zephyr I'm sorry I have mixed up rows and columns. The program is supposed to convert any Number from any Number system(hexadezimal, binary ...) into decimal System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your use of a `StackPane` may be blocking mouse events from registering on your RadioButtons.

While I don't usually do this, below is a reconfigured layout that you might use as a jumping off point for your code.  I've simplified the layout quite a bit and all RadioButtons are functioning as desired:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class scratch_1 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Label lblTitle = new Label("Gib die Basis und die Zahl ein!");
        root.getChildren().add(lblTitle);

        // The input TextField
        TextField txtInput = new TextField();
        root.getChildren().add(txtInput);

        // HBox to hold our three columns
        HBox hBoxSelections = new HBox(20);
        hBoxSelections.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Use a GridPane for our RadioButton grid
        GridPane gridSelections = new GridPane();
        gridSelections.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridSelections.setHgap(10);
        gridSelections.setVgap(5);

        // Our ToggleGroup to which all RadioButtons will belong
        ToggleGroup groupSelections = new ToggleGroup();

        // We need 11 rows of 3 RadioButtons, let's use a couple of for loops to populate the GridPane
        int counter = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton("" + counter);
                radioButton.setToggleGroup(groupSelections);

                gridSelections.add(radioButton, j, i);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        // Let's add the GridPane to our root layout
        root.getChildren().add(gridSelections);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

> **Result:**

[image: screenshot]

---

Note that I worked from your prior code posting as therefore the above sample does not include your `update()` method (or any logic, for that matter).